# ASMX web service debugging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

How can i turn on debugging when trying to add a service to my VB.net app? How can i change the settings to view it remotely? I tried loading up the .asmx page in IE on that server where the file is being hosted and it just asked me to save the file-would never open it to view as a page.

That is the error i get when i try to load the .asmx file from my server.
[image: the error]

Comment: Yes... when i placed that into the code it still gives me that.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "vb.net asp.net" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @StealthRT: if you have a problem with the editing, you should say what it is instead of engaging in rollback wars. If you have a reason to roll back an edit,it will likely be respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy that `customerrors` tag and paste it into the web config file exactly as shown, you'll get the same error screen, but it will show you a detailed error message, which should help you track down the underlying problem.